# Specific letters and digit in a string in c programming

Tags: c

How to check for user input if I want to start with a character follow by 7 digit and end with a letter in c programming?
Example; S1234567A

Comment: I really do not know how to start?? I only know to check specific letter or digit by string

Answer (score 3):

Just check the input string letter by letter, with standard functions in `ctypes.h`, e.g., `isdigit` to check digits, and `isalpha` to check letters.